# How to store a root domain as a variable in php and use it to move between folders

Tags: php, html, variables, indexing, header

I am in the process of creating a website using php and due to hosting my website locally and then uploading it onto a server I want an easy way of changing the root domain without manually changing it in every single place I have a domain, so I proposed storing the root domain as a variable. *n.b. I have simplified down the names of the files.*

I created a a variable called $rootDomain

```
<?php
$rootDomain = "http://localhost/testWebsite/";
?>
```

Next I have a new page in a sub folder called: *page.php*. I get to this page via a link in a header that is used for all the pages.

```
<a href=<?php  $rootDomain?>"pageone/page.php"><li><?php echo$firstLink?></li>
```

Using the generic header I have on all pages I want to get back to the main index page. The link used looks like this:

```
<a href=<?php  $rootDomain?>"index.php"><?php echo$websiteName?></a>
```

The expected link location should send me to:

```
"http://localhost/testWebsite/index.php"
```

But the link it is displaying is:

```
"http://localhost/testWebsite/pageone/index.php"
```

Which is an error.

When I have tested it using the link directly without the variable :

```
<a href="http://localhost/index.php"><?php echo$websiteName?></a>
```

There is no error and I get the expected outcome.

I am struggling to work out what I am doing wrong and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `<a href=<?php  $rootDomain?>"pageone/page.php">` - missing the `echo` statement but other than that... if `pageone` is not intended why is it there? Also - can you not use root relative links and thus `/index.php` will always be the index page at site root?

Comment: There should normally be no need to use absolute URLs all over the place to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `echo` the variable in the `href` attribute with PHP for it to show in the HTML output.

You can do so by doing

```
    <a href="<?php echo $rootDomain; ?>index.php"><?php echo $websiteName; ?></a>
```

or you can use the short echo syntax

```
    <a href="<?= $rootDomain ?>index.php"><?= $websiteName ?></a>
```

You also have a couple typos in your code, like the misplaced quotes around the `href` attribute.